# UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to refactor packages

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I got an already made Android project which use C++ with JNI.

When I'm trying to rename the packages of the project I get an error saying that there are native methods and "Running the modified program will cause UnsatisfiedLinkError".

So how can I rename my packages?

Comment: Change the names of your exported C/C++ functions accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible causes for the error which you got are

- .so library is not generating for the required cpu architecture
- Loading `System.loadLibrary` is not being called properly
- Methods or parameter of the methods which you are calling doesn't
  exist or matching with native library
- Package which is being used with JNI code are not match with java
  native class(which has native methods)
  Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE)

If possible than please post code which will be help full to short out issue..

Comment: There might be a better way but I simply changed some of the names manually. There were some methods definitions with the old package names and I changed it manually.

Comment: @YonatanNir if the problem is from mentioned possible causes give upvote or mark as answer

Comment: I've already marked it as an answer even before commenting. Congratulations on an accpted answer ;)